# How does iTunes Match handle metadata?

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

When I purchase songs from iTunes, I often times hate the way the MetaData is presented. For example, I prefer the format

```
Artist          Song Name 
-------------------------
artist_name     song_name f/ featured_artists
```

But songs purchased from iTunes usually come in the form

```
Artist                                    Song Name
---------------------------------------------------
artist_name feat. featured_artists        song_name
```

My concern is that once I use iTunes match to match all of my music with the music that exists on Apple's servers, iTunes is going to use the MetaData as stored on their servers as opposed to the MetaData that I have meticulously set in my library.

If it is going to use Apple's MetaData instead of my own, this is a complete deal breaker for me.

Does anybody who has signed up for/used iTunes Match know the way iTunes Match behaves in this regard?

Comment: Does it only keep the items you customized? That is yes, in the notes section of each song I've added words and created smart playlists that pull in songs based on those words. Like Dance, Slow, Gym, etc. So would like to keep those (which it appears it will), however everything else I didn't customize I'd want replaced with iTunes version. Such as the official name of the song album, etc if any of the data is wrong. So does it simply not touch any of your meta (which would suck), or does it only not touch items you've edited yourself iTunes, which would be perfect?

Comment: I would assume it doesn't touch any of your metadata, raged less if you have touched it or not. I'm not sure though.For future reference, I think this would be better as a separate question or a comment to the other response since it does not answer my question. Someone more familiar with the stack exhange philosophy might be able to confirm this though.

Comment: There has been enough interest (myself included) in getting iTunes Match to replace my metadata with metadata from the iTunes Store that I've asked it as a separate question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31357/is-it-possible-to-use-itunes-match-to-replace-my-existing-metadata-with-metadata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It keeps your custom metadata!

Comment: great, even when downloading the music to iOS devices? Even after deleting from iTunes and re-downloading from iCloud?

Comment: Of course. Wouldn't make much sense if it didn't. During the initial scan (match period), it sets all that information in the cloud. Any time you access the song, it will have that metadata. If you change it, those changes will also be reflected in the cloud. You may wish to hit up this link. It's a pretty expansive coverage of the service: http://www.macrumors.com/2011/11/14/a-clear-explanation-of-itunes-match/