# Is it possible to use iTunes Match to replace my existing metadata with metadata from the iTunes Store?

Tags: metadata, itunes-match

My music in my iTunes library has come from many sources over the years, and it's filled with incomplete or inaccurate or simply missing data, not to mention the fact that most of my stuff doesn't have album art associated with it.

I had hoped that as part of the 256kbps 'upgrade' functionality that iTunes would also upgrade the metadata on my songs to the metadata that they ship with the iTunes Store purchases. However, deleting and redownloading a matched song only upgrades the audio data, but keeps the metadata intact. Is there a way to upgrade the metadata as well?

Comment: Wow - I wonder where iTunes is storing your metadata on deleted tracks. Have you considered setting up a small library as a test and placing two songs into the cloud with odd data and then deleting the entire iTunes library? Perhaps there isn't a good way to clear the data so polluting the store might not be a great idea...

Comment: did you try third-party app like http://www.tuneupmedia.com/index.php?gclid=CLOG9O6ugKQCFVMB4wodwXfkHA

Comment: @Am1rr3zA No, I haven't tried that or any other app. It's not clear where those kinds of apps get their data from, and they often cost money. I was somewhat hoping for a way to do it directly through iTunes and iTunes Match

Comment: @KyleCronin I spend lots of time for doing what you said but can't find any solution :(

Comment: @Am1rr3zA I appreciate you trying. I suspect it was an intentional omission on Apple's part.

Comment: @bmike I suspect the answer to your question is `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml` or `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl`. It could also be in the `itdb` for all we know.

Comment: Try http://beaugil.es/2012/03/fix-metadata-with-itunes-match/, that helps :) Sadly, I cannot add this as a real answer to your question due to reputation lack...

Comment: I realize I'm late to the party, but I actually had the same issue, and was hoping that it would fix meta as well. I did however, find a way to do so. https://code.google.com/archive/p/itunes-match-tagger/ worked pretty good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the design clearly is intended to honor whatever set of metadata you have currently entered into your library. As you have discovered, the matching process can find songs based on other criteria and re-downloading the "canonical" AAC 256 kbps stereo will not currently fill in any metadata holes or correct parts of the metadata that do not match what Apple has in the store (or it's Match database for songs that are not for sale like the AC/DC catalog)

I can see two reasons for this:

1. Intentional - preserve user customization where the data may be better on the individual customer iTunes database.
2. Not automating the process of cleaning up songs that may have been passed or downloaded rather than ripped when connected to a metadata lookup server or otherwise encoded by the official artist when it was sold or released.

I specifically have hundreds of Hawaiian songs where I've entered the metadata with the help of a native speaker to have the correct punctuation (and that doesn't match Apple's punctuation). There certainly is a great need for a tool to help people manage this, but iTunes Match isn't that tool today.

Answer (score 1):

At least for the missing data you could try out [matchTag](http://tune-instructor.de/com/matchTag/app.html) (German page). It claims that it will replace missing data directly with Apple's data when you (re)load the songs with iTunes Match.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried iTunes Match yet, so I don't know if the following is already working.

Apple should give the users the ability to "Get track names" option in iTunes once you subscribe. For now that service is only allowed for CD's imported directly into iTunes.

That way would be the users choice to upgrade the meta-data of the matched songs. And almost everything they need to enable that is already implemented.

I have been able to fetch some album artwork directly from iTunes, so that part should work already. I suppose the albums it does not get the artwork for are not recognized in their database.